# NodeJS SSL on host, how can i get it to work?

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to enable SSL on my website but i just can't get it to work, even though i set up the whole code in my app.js file...
whenever i have http.createServer it works and the browser says: Not Secure...
But when i add https.createServer the server stops working at all. the website is live and i have generated the certificate and also tried copying the real one that came with the domain, but no luck...

here is my code that works:

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    app = express()
    expressStatic = require("express-static"),
    https = require('https'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require("path");



app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("homepage")
})

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client-key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client-cert.pem')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client.ca-bundle'))
};


// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Here is the one that doesn't work at all:

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    app = express()
    expressStatic = require("express-static"),
    typedJS = require("typed.js"),
    https = require('https'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require("path");



app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("homepage")
})

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client-key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client-cert.pem')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('https/client.ca-bundle'))
};


// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Should i stick to the SSL that came with my domain or the one i generate or what?
How can i get it to work? i also tried using express-force-ssl with no luck as well.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of SSL certificate do you have? If you have a wildcard certificate or a certificate for a specific domain, make sure the URL is pointed at port 443 for the server that you're running the Node.JS application on